# Не подключается к Mysql после добавления Unicode в my.cnf PHP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, char, charset

Всем привет.
После добавления вот этих строк в /etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
init_connect=‘SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci’
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci

[client]
default-character-set = utf8
```

При подключении к БД через PDO вылетает такая ошибка:

```
Warning: PDO::query(): SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1184 
Aborted connection 4 to db: 'metro' user: 'metro_u' host: '192.168.33.10' 
(init_connect command failed) in /var/www/html/oop/exp_2.php on line 87
```

При этом, если закомментировать вышеприведенные строки - тот же скрипт работает без проблем.

Я так понимаю ошибка из-за несоответствия кодировок в апач, сервере mysql и php.
Вопрос - куда копать? )))

Comment: вам же прямо написали `init_connect command failed`

Comment: а зачем вам в cnf файле записывать? Присылайте команду после подключения к бд

Comment: ваши команды могут противоречить друг другу http://gahcep.github.io/blog/2013/01/05/mysql-utf8/

Comment: @ArchDemon в случае ошибки подключения к БД текст ошибки получите не в той кодировке, так что мб есть смысл. Да какой смысл каждый раз выполнять команду, если можно настроить?

Comment: @teran, ну не всегда на хостингах есть возможность править конфиги. К тому же в PDO можно передать команды инициализации в подключение. Не знаю, повлияет ли на кодировку текста ошибки, но лично у меня с этим проблем не возникало.

Answer (score 0):

Короче всё решилось просто:
1. use mysql
1.1 ALTER DATABASE mysql CHARACTER SET latin COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

2. При создании новой БД указывать кодировку UTF8(или любую другую, которая записана в .cnf - файле - !важно! чтобы везде был один и тот же чарсет).

Конфликт был из-за несовместимости передаваемой кодировки.

Собственно всё )))